# Mini batch stochastic gradient descent

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation, gradient-descent

My question is what changes should be made to SGD algorithm to implement mini-batch SGD algorithm.

In the book, [Machine Learning](https://www.cs.ubbcluj.ro/~gabis/ml/ml-books/McGrawHill%20-%20Machine%20Learning%20-Tom%20Mitchell.pdf) by Tom Mitchell, the GD, and SGD algorithms are explained very well. Here is a snippet of the book for SGD backpropagation algorithm:

[image]

I know that the difference between `SGD` and `mini-batch SGD` is that in the former we use one training example to update weights in each iteration (of the outer while-loop), while in the latter, a batch of training examples should be used in each iteration. But I still can't figure how the below algorithm should be changed to account for this change.

Here is what I think it should look like, but can't confirm this from several tutorials I followed on the web.

```
Until the termination condition is met, Do
  batch <- get next batch
  For each <x,t> in batch, Do
    1- Propagate the input forward through the network.
    2- d_k += o_k(1 - o_k)(t_k - o_k) 
    3- d_h += o_h(1 - o_h)sum(w_kh * d_k)
  For each network weight w_ij, Do
    w_ji += etha * d_j * x_ij
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What *exactly* is your *question*?

Comment: @desertnaut How to change the above algorithm to implement mini-batch SGD? (updated the question)

Comment: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/17/stochastic-gradient-descent-sgd-with-python/